# It's almost the same function but one is working and the other no

Tags: python, python-3.x

my problem is that these two functions (in my opinion the same) one works and the other does not, any suggestions?

```
fr = open("numeri.txt", "r")

def numMax(file):
    i = 1
    maxNum = 0
    for n in file:
        n = int(n)
        if i == 1 or n > maxNum:
            maxNum = n
        i += 1
    return maxNum

def numMin(file):
    i = 1
    minNum = 0
    for n in file:
        n = int(n)
        if i == 1 or n < minNum:
            minNum = n
        i += 1
    return minNum
    
print("The max is", numMax(fr))
print("The min is", numMin(fr))

fr.close()
```

The file contents:
20
47
174
29
117
29
29
62
55
71
89
177
27
178
96
-8
116
132
188
63
129

Comment: You start with `minNum = 0`. Then you check if `n < minNum`. Think about it

Comment: in reality if it is on the first turn n is the same as the first one inserted. concerns as well